# Is there a way to prevent direct login after registration in FirebaseAuth?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

When creating a user using the `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` method in FirebaseAuth, it directly changes the `currentUser` to that newly created user.

> If the new account was created, the user is also signed in. In the
> callback, you can use the getCurrentUser method to get the user's
> account data.

Is there a way to prevent this action from happening by default?

I want the user to first `register` and then `login` using the same credentials he used for registration?

I am currently working in kotlin, android but I think the solution to this is applicable to all languages implementing Firebase.

Comment: I'm having this issue as well

Answer (score 0):

Use the signout function(Inside success listener) when the user is registered successfully.